# How to overcome segmentation error while implementing the temperature conversion?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner to C language and I'm writing through a practice question where I use functions to convert between Fahrenheit and Celsius. I have written the program using 2 functions: one to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius and another vice verca:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int celsius2fahrenheit(int celsius, int fahrenheit){
        fahrenheit = (9/5) * celsius + 32;
        printf("%d", fahrenheit);
    }

    int fahrenheit2celsius(int fahrenheit, int celsius){
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5/9);
        printf("%d", celsius);
    }

    int main(void){
        int celsius, fahrenheit;
        celsius = fahrenheit = 0;
        printf("-----------------Menu-----------------\n");
        printf("Option 1. Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
        printf("Option 2. Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");

        printf("\n");
        printf("Option: ");

        int Option;
        scanf("%d", Option);

        if (Option == 1){
            printf("Enter the temperature (Celsius) : ");
            scanf("%d", celsius);
            printf("\n");
            celsius2fahrenheit(celsius, fahrenheit); 
        }
        else if (Option == 2){
            printf("Enter the temperature (Fahrenheit) : ");
            scanf("%d", fahrenheit);
            printf("\n");
            fahrenheit2celsius(fahrenheit, celsius);
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Option");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

When the program was compiled, the error messages occur:
"Segmentation fault" after executing the option to select the operation. I assume there was something wrong with the variable declaration but I'm not too sure.

Comment: check type of second argument of scanf() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: A segmentation fault is caused by accessing memory which isn't owned by the program, or data is not in the format expected (leading to the invalid operation downstream). Could you perhaps simplify your example code to the minimum needed to demonstrate your problem eg: you could hard-code the input to something like option=1, celsius=36. That would allow you to separate the issue of input from the processing of the input. (if that program then runs, then it's an input problem)

Comment: `int celcsius` and `scanf("%d", celsius);`  - you need to pass a _pointer_ to the variable in scanf.

Comment: Note that your conversion functions are doing **integer** arithmetic. So `(9/5)` evaluates to `1` and `(5/9)` is `0`. That should help explain the next bug you're going to find.

Comment: You only need one parameter per function, and you don't return anything despite declaring an `int` return type.

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing '&' in your scanf functions (line 23, 27 and 33)

Also you should take the values as floats to get more accurate results, because right now answers comes as integer..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

float fh,cl;
int choice;

printf("\n1: Convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius."); 
printf("\n2: Convert temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit.");
printf("\nEnter your choice (1, 2): ");
scanf("%d",&choice);

if(choice ==1){
    printf("\nEnter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%f",&fh);
    cl= (fh - 32) / 1.8;
    printf("Temperature in Celsius: %.2f",cl);
}
else if(choice==2){
    printf("\nEnter temperature in Celsius: ");
    scanf("%f",&cl);
    fh= (cl*1.8)+32;
    printf("Temperature in Fahrenheit: %.2f",fh);
}
else{
    printf("\nInvalid Choice !!!");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**scanf** needs the specifier and the memory address of the variable.

```cpp
scanf("%d", &Option);
```

Note that `Option` and `&Option` are two different things. `&` means the memory address where the variable is located.

Change each one in the code (line 27 and 33).